# Actionscript 3 - Class Referring Errors

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I a document class (`Main`) and a class connected to a symbol (`MainMenu`), and I get an error I just can't figure how to solve.. I get this error:

> 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

it is reffering to "`public var mainMenu = new MainMenu();`" in my document class.

Anyways, here are my classes:

Main(document class):

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public var mainMenu = new MainMenu();



    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        startGame();
    }

        public function startGame(){
            addChild(mainMenu);     
        }

        public function initGame(event){
            //Adding player and such..

        }

}
```

}

MainMenu:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class MainMenu extends MovieClip {

    private var logo = new Logo(); 


    public function MainMenu(main:Main) {
        // constructor code
        mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);  
        logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, main.initGame);
        placeButtons(event);
        }

    public function placeButtons(event:Event){
        logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initGame);
        logo.x = - logo.width/2;
        logo.y = 50;
        addChild(logo);

        trace ("MainMenu added");
    }

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: public var mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);

Comment: except that since he's creating that instance prior to create the main instance this will refer to nothing.

Comment: Remove this line:  mainMenu = new MainMenu(this); from MainMenu.  It's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers...

- Be mindful of your indentation.
- Datatype your variables, arguments, and function returns.
- Your MainMenu class was self instantiating itself (that's an infinite loop)
- If you really need direct access to another classes function, consider making the child class extend the parent class.  Alternatively, you could make the specific function a static function and call the function directly off the class without passing variable references.  For example: `Main.initGame()`

Here are your classes, with a potential solution...

---

**Main:**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public var mainMenu:MainMenu;

        public function Main() {
            mainMenu = new MainMenu();
            addChild(mainMenu);
        }

        public function initGame(e:Event):void {
            //Adding player and such..
        }
    }
}
```

**MainMenu:**

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MainMenu extends MovieClip {
        private var logo:Logo;

        public function MainMenu() {
            // Wait for it to be added to the parent.
            logo = new Logo();
            addChild(logo);
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, placeButton);
        }

        private function placeButton(e:Event):void {
            // We only need this to happen once, so remove the listener
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, placeButton);

            // Now that we've formed the connection, we can reference the function dynamically
            logo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["parent"].initGame);

            logo.x = - logo.width/2;
            logo.y = 50;
        }
    }
}
```

I've left the structure as similar to your original intent as possible, but the above function reference is poor form.  As a general rule, children should not have connections to their parents as it's a potential memory leak.  You might instead add the event listener from your Main class.

Comment: Thank you! But when I change that, I get this error: 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1. It is pointing towards "            mainMenu = new MainMenu();".

Comment: In the implementation above, `MainMenu` accepts no arguments.  Make sure you have saved out an updated copy of bother `Main` and `MainMenu`

Comment: They are both updated. I even tried to copy both your scripts and use them instead, still the same error message..

Comment: I was just about to upload a project for you which had the above running, but I'm glad you got it working.  :)